# Debug Service Fabric DNX/asp.net 5 Stateless Service in Azure Cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have published my dnx/Web Service Fabric stateless service to local - it works.  I publish to the cloud (carefully setting up the correct ports) and it does not start correctly.  The error is the usual partition is below replica count

My suspicion is that dnx is not installed by default on the cluster VMs.  Any way to get around that?  I don't appear to get a login to those VMs so I can install asp.net 5 manually.

Comment: I know you said you carefully set up the correct ports, but just as a sanity check, can you make sure you have Protocol="http" in your Endpoint config in ServiceManifest.xml? Should look like this: <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" Protocol="http" Port="80" />

Comment: Also everything you need to run dnx should be in the packages that deploy with the asp.net 5 service (unless that's changed recently, but I'm pretty sure the whole point was that you don't need to install anything on the host machine).

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue - it was not DNX.

I set up a new cluster and was able to log in.  There are 22304 error messages saying that my second non-dnx stateless service which is in the same application package is causing this event:

> .NET Runtime version : 4.0.30319.34014 - This application could not be started.This application requires one of the following versions of the .NET Framework:
>    .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2
>
> Do you want to install this .NET Framework version now?

I'll figure out how to target correctly.